# Setting images to 2 imageView from Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I have 2 imageView where I want to set images to from the Camera Intent. I'm having the below issues when I wish someone can help enlighten me.

1. When I take the first photo supposedly to set to imageView1, it set to imageView2. This first photo is supposed to set to imageView1.
2. When I take a second photo and save the image from camera to set to imageView1, my app crashes. This second photo is supposed to set to imageView2.

My code used is as below.

```
    public void Camera (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        file1 = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file1);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && imageView1 == null) {
                imageView1.setImageURI(file1);
            } else {
                imageView2.setImageURI(file1);
            }
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
                                                                                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:783)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:673)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:407)
                                                                                 at MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:117)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3514)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3561)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks!!

Comment: Post you logcat

Comment: `if ( .. imageView1 == null) {
                imageView1.setImageURI(file1);
            }`. Is this a typo? It would crash with an NPE this way. But that's not the error your logcat showed.

Comment: LogCat added. Tks!

Comment: Hi Rob, not a typo. It's my coding error. Tks!

Comment: I've change it to this if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { imageView1.setImageURI(file1);. It does set 1st photo to imageView1 now but app crashes upon saving 2nd photo.

Comment: This XML code 'android:largeHeap="true"' prevented the app from crashing but I need to set 2nd photo to imageView2 still. Any help or ideas will be appreciated. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the results i wanted setting the 2 images to their respective imageViews. My amended code is as below.

```
public void Camera (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (file1 == null) {
        file1 = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    } else {

        file2 = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file2);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageView1.setImageURI(file1);
        }
    } else {
        imageView2.setImageURI(file2);
    }
}
```

However, if I take a 3rd photo, it will set to imageView2....need to rectify this.

If I start another app without closing this app, when i return to it, the images are not displayed on the imageViews anymore.